# Merging a deleted file in git

Tags: git

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered before, but all the search results I get are about restoring a deleted file, not transferring the deletion.

In one branch, I have deleted many files, and added many as well. I would like to merge only the deletions into another branch. So if file foo.js has been deleted and file bar.js has been added in branch1, I'd like to somehow make sure that foo.js has been deleted in branch2, but that bar.js has *not* been added to branch2.

I know I can just do a checkout with a path to pull in new files, but I don't know of a way to do it to transfer a deletion.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: easiest would be add all the deleted files to a commit and then merge that commit, In another commit stage all the added files. This way you can easily differentiate whats deleted and whats added

Comment: @uDaY: is there an easy way to do that retroactively? right now, the additions and deletions are spread around several commits